# Trigger insertar, actualizar

Tags: sql-server

Hola me pueden ayudar con un trigger? Quiero que, si se mueve algun data de la tabla clasificaciones, se haga una insertacion si el dato no existe en la tabla historial o, si existe, solo actualice el dato.

Tengo el codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER test
ON [dbo].[CLASIFICACIONES]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--DECLARE @Activity  NVARCHAR (50)

-- update
    IF EXISTS (SELECT C1, C2, C4, C3, '2', '3', C5  FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT C1, C2, C4, C3, '2', '3', C5  FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE KDIHCS SET C4=C3, C5='1', C6='2', C7=C5 
    END

    -- insert
    IF EXISTS (SELECT C1, C2, C4, C3, '2', '3', C5 FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO HISTORIAL
        SELECT C1, C2, C4, C3, '2', '3', C5 FROM INSERTED
    END
END
```

ASI LO LLEVO PERO NO ME FUNCIONA AUN BIEN

El problema es que no consigo que actualice si ya tengo dato agregado o insertado.

Comment: estas usando oracle o mysql? por que las 2 etiquetas?

Comment: ES SQL SERVER PERDON

Comment: ¿Que columnas habría que actualizar? ¿Cual la FK de `HISTORIAL` que se relaciona con `CLASIFICACIONES`?

Comment: las columnas de historial a actualizar son c4,c5,c6,c7 su las llaves que relacionan son c1 y c2

Comment: @PatricioMoracho me respondi para mostrarte como la llevo la query

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta (usa el link editar debajo de la misma) e incluye la definición de las tablas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si al insertar en la tabla A quieres insertar en la tabla B, y al actualizar en la tabla A, quieres actualizar en la tabla B, entonces recomendaría realizar varios cambios con respecto del *trigger* publicado en tu pregunta:

- Dado que el trigger solo se dispara después de `insert` o `update`, para determinar si es un `update` basta ver si hay algún dato en la *pseudo tabla* `deleted`. Si no lo hay, podemos estar seguros que es un `insert`.
- Hay que tomar en cuenta que puede tratarse de una operación masiva, ya que en *SQL Server*, los *triggers* no se lanzan para cada fila que se inserta, modifica o elimina. Se lanzan una sola vez, aún cuando la instrucción de marras esté modificando o insertando múltiples registros, por lo mismo, la estrategia de `insert`/`update` debe tener esto en cuenta.
- Para actualizar me valgo de la instrucción `update/from` que es exclusiva de *SQL Server*, pero que se me hace muy cómoda en estos casos. Si no estas familiarizado con ella, recomiendo su estudio.
- Para insertar, hago un `insert/select`, de manera que inserto todos los registros que devuelve el `select`.

Con esto en cuenta, el trigger quedaría algo así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
ON [dbo].[CLASIFICACIONES]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  if exists (select 1 from deleted) 
  begin
    --es un update, actualizamos:
    update b
       set   c3 = i.c3
           , c4 = i.c4
           , c5 = i.c5
           , c6 = i.c6
      from inserted i
           inner join KDIHCS b on b.c1 = i.c1 and b.c2 = i.c2;
  end
  else 
  begin
    --es un registro nuevo, también lo insertamos
    insert into KDIHCS (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6)
    select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6
      from inserted;
  end;
  set nocount off;
END
go
```

Puede ser que los nombres de los campos no coincidan, no tengo a mano la estructura de tus tablas. La idea es que analices la solución planteada y la adaptes a tu caso particular.

Comment: gracias @jachguate si me sirvio ya no mas la adapte a mi codigo me sirvio mucho, la query que yo puse lo hacia bien en insert pero cuando le tocaba actualizar decia que lo hacia pero no se reflejaba volvia a hacer el update y ahi ponia lo que debio poner el primer update lo hacia como desfazado este me funciono de maravilla era lo que necesitaba, gracias

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda @JavierSolis, un saludo!